# Passport.js OAuth2Strategy response not containing refresh token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Currently, I have an Oauth2 flow for an API. The code works but I dont believe it is working the way it should.

```
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2');

passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: authorizationURL, 
    tokenURL: tokenURL, 
    clientID: clientId, 
    clientSecret: clientSecret, 
    callbackURL: callbackURL,    
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, results, profile, callback) {
    return callback(null, results);
}))

app.get('/auth/api', passport.authenticate('oauth2', {failureRedirect: '/fail', successRedirect: '/', scope: ['profile']}));
```

I manage to get an `accestoken`, `refreshtoken`and `results` in the callback function, however, minor problems are occuring. The first is that profile is returning an empty object `{}`. I dont believe passport can do anything about this due to the stratergy not being native to the API. The other problem is that `results` is returning the accesstoken and its expiration but it doesnt return the refresh token in the results. The thing I dont understand is that the `refreshtoken` callback parameter is returining the refresh token but the result doesnt contain it.

What I expect to recieve accoring to the api documentation is:

```
{
  access_token: "...",
  expires_in: 300,
  refresh_expires_in: 1800,
  refresh_token: "...",
  token_type: "bearer",
  'not-before-policy': 0,
  scope: "profile"
}
```

but what im getting is:

```
{
  access_token: '...',
  expires_in: 900,
  refresh_expires_in: 0,
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  'not-before-policy': 0,
  scope: 'offline_access email profile'
}
```

I could just merge the `refreshtoken` and the `results` together but if this is the current outcome, surely im doing something wrong. Is this to do with the stratergy im using?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the callback receives only four parameters:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
...
}
```

There is no `results` parameter. Still, you can pass to your callback (`cb` in the code above) anything you like from the things you received in the passport's callback. If you have the refresh token in the `refreshToken` parameter, then just pass it to your `cb` if you need it there.